# serialization issue in django

Tags: python, django, serialization

i am new to django and i an trying to add serialized responses

following is my models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    numofsubs = models.IntegerField()
    namesofsubs= models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    details = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    class Meta:

         db_table = "student"
```

here is my serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Student

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('name' ,' degree',' numofsubs' , 'namesofsubs',  'details')
```

following is my code for views.py

```
def addStudent(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = StudentSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return HttpResponse('Failed')


def getAllStudents(request):
    objects = Student.objects.all()
    serializer = StudentSerializer(objects, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

i have added `'rest_framework'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `setting.py`

now when ever i hit the url to add new student ar to get a list of all the students server gives Server Error(500) in response.

Edit1 :
here is the response i get in browser

> 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'

and here is the code from views.py that browser is highlighting

> serializer = StudentSerializer(data=request.data)

Edit2:

here is my html form

```
<html>
    <title>Add New Student</title>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="/addstudent/">
        name : <input type="text" name="name">
        degree : <input type="text" name="url">

        numofsubs : <input type="number" name="numofsubs">
        nameofsubs : <input type="text" name="nameofsubs">
        details : <input type="text" name="details">
        <button type="submit"> submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Would probably help if you added exact error / stacktrace, the '500 internal server error' is basically just saying "something went wrong".

Comment: there are no errors on server , [17/Aug/2017 07:44:22]"POST /addstudent/ HTTP/1.1" 500 27. this is all what i get on server

Comment: set `DEBUG=True` in your settings and try again.

Comment: @BearBrown i have added the browser's response after changing debugging to true

Comment: i edit answer, you use restfarmawork and django view it is strange

Comment: i am new to django and restframework , can you please guid me how should i do it?